# Linkage issue when using Poco C++ 1.3.6 for iPhone Xcode project

Tags: c++, iphone, poco-libraries

I managed to compile Poco C++ 1.3.6 library for iPhone by the following commands:

```
./configure --config=iPhone --no-tests --omit=Data,Cryptor,NetSSL_OpenSSL  
./make
```

Then I created a new view-based Application for iPhone and add Header search paths and changed my .m file to .mm. And then I added the newly compiled .a files into my Xcode project. When I hit "Build & Go", I encountered a few linkage errors such as:

```
Poco::Zip::ZipArchieve .... Symbol(s) not found
```

By using the same way I successfully compiled and linked my testing static library `libtest.a`. But I failed to link Poco C++ libraries. I don't know whether it's a bug or I missed something.

Can anybody help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define POCO_STATIC in your project. Apparently, unless POCO_STATIC is defined, Poco headers attempt to use the dynamic libraries.